# Large MySQL statement returning thousands of rows with redundant information

Tags: mysql

I know broadly that my problem is, broadly, that the way I am making my joins is resulting in a lot of information being repeated over and over and over. What I don't know is to trim this down:

What's happening is that all of the `ON` clauses are being dynamically generated from a form; this statement below should be returning about ~1500 rows; it returns 32000.

I'm not sure if providing my table associations will be helpful; I have the sense that I'm just generally missing the point somewhere, but if more information is required please ask, I will provide!

Help hugely appreciated.

```
SELECT  `Appraisal`.`id` AS `Appraisal ID`,
                    `Appraisal`.`module_id` AS `Module ID`,
                    `Module`.`name` AS `Module Name`,
                    `Course`.`coursecode` AS `Course Code`,
                    `Appraisal`.`excerpt_id` AS `Excerpt ID`,
                    `Appraisal`.`user_id` AS `User ID`,
                    `Appraisal`.`attempt_id` AS `Attempt ID`,
                    `Excerpt`.`id` AS `Excerpt ID`,
                    `Appraisal`.`response` AS `Response (Y=1)`,
                    `Appraisal`.`correct` AS `Response Correct (c=1)`,
                    `Excerpt`.`type` AS `Excerpt Type`,
                    `Appraisal`.`confidence` AS `Confidence (n/100)`,
                    `Appraisal`.`time` AS `Response Time (ms)`,
                    `Institution`.`name` AS `Institution Name`
                     FROM `appraisals` AS `Appraisal`
                    JOIN `modules` AS `Module` ON (`Appraisal`.`module_id` = `Module`.`id`)
                    JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Appraisal`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
                    JOIN `users_courses` AS `UsersCourse` ON (`UsersCourse`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
                    JOIN `courses` AS `Course` ON (`UsersCourse`.`course_id` = `Course`.`id`)
                    JOIN `institutions` AS `Institution` ON (`Course`.`institution_id` = `Institution`.`id`)
                    JOIN `excerpts_modules` as `ExcerptsModule` ON (`Module`.`id` = `ExcerptsModule`.`module_id`)
                    JOIN `excerpts` as `Excerpt` ON (`ExcerptsModule`.`excerpt_id` = `Excerpt`.`id`)
                 WHERE `Institution`.`id` = '1' AND 
`Course`.`educator_id` = '2' AND 
`Course`.`id` IN ('1','2') AND 
`Module`.`id` = '1' AND 
`User`.`id` IN ('1','2','3','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28')
```

Also, if it gives some context, `ON` clauses are all supplied from an HTML form that looks like this:
[image]

## UPDATE

Here's a screen cap of 1 `Appraisal`'s data; each appraisal, I've now worked out, is being duplicated 32 times (though I am sure 32 is a number that owes to context):
[image]

What's worth noting is that the `Institution` column (it's cut off), the `Response Time` column and several others never change; it's the combination of the `Excerpt Type` and something else (I think) that's causing the problem. There *cannot* be more than one `Excerpt` or `Excerpt Type` per appraisal.

**Minor Update**
There are 30 `excerpts` attached to the current `excerpts_module` table, and consequently what's happening, at least, is that every `Appraisal` is getting joined to every `Excerpt`. There should only be one, however. I don't know how to make this constraint and still include that single excerpt (ie. without that join, the next line that joins `excerpts` can't succeed).  :/ For those who  have been helping, thanks so much, I am nubbing this for sure.

## Final Update (SOLVED)

Thanks to comments below and a little inferential insight on my own part, this proved to be resolved by three steps:

1. Adding constraints to prevent duplicates in some of the join tables;
2. One of my joins was designed poorly and this was a context-specific problem; but
3. `SELECT DISTINCT` did (contrary to my comment below) prove critical after I fixed by bad join

Thanks StackOverflow (will answer this in 24 hrs when allowed, or if one of my helpful commenters wants to I'll remove this update and mark correct).

Comment: Your joins (or your expectations) are wrong.  Remove the joins one-by-one until you spot what the problem is.

Comment: What is being duplicated? Can you use `group by`? - An SQL fiddle with DDL and a small set of example data would be useful

Comment: Yeah, that'll take me a few minutes to put together but I surely will, brb.

Comment: Query looks quite alright at first glance. I think having the relations between the tables might be necessary after all. Either you are missing a join condition, or there is just so much data. I started an answer to analyse possible causes, but it's just guessing without table structure. Constraints are especially important. Can a user be linked to a course only once (combi of userid and courseid is unique in user_courses), or can there be multiple? Same for other tables.

Comment: Hrmmm this was a really handy insight; I am indeed finding duplicates of users_courses. I am no SQL wizard; this is overwhelmingly the most complex thing I've ever written. What information can I post to be of more use?

Comment: Well, that was a big help; down to 24000 results, also makes me think this might be the general form of the problem between other tables.

Comment: Did you try with `SELECT DISTINCT` , to see what happens ? Sometimes this could be a quick solution while you enhance your SQL .

Comment: I have now, haha. No dice.  Generally it looks like I am getting 32 of each appraisal, wherein basically every combination of the added-in columns Ive made on the fly are present; going to add a sample of the data to my question....

Comment: btw.. sometimes de-normalization is a great concept to apply xD

Comment: I do not know what this is! As you can tell I am a designer who got roped into doing some development for my university and I am fumbling through.